# HTA: Show MsgBox when all boxes are unchecked

Tags: html, checkbox, vbscript, hta

I'm still new to HTA, and i'm looking to add a warning when no checkboxes are selected and when no checkboxes are selected it suppresses the current MsgBox which says that all checkboxes are processed.

The current MsgBox's will be replaced with a objShell.Run line (robocopy).

I know my code is probably a bit basic, so suggestions to make it more efficiënt are most welcome.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sync Tool</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Sync Tool"
  ID="SyncTool"
  VERSION="1.0.0"
  BORDER="dialog"
  MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  SCROLL="no"
  SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
  CONTEXTMENU="no"
  SELECTION="no"/>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Sub Window_OnLoad
    Dim width,height
    width=330
    height=310
    self.ResizeTo width,height
    self.MoveTo (screen.AvailWidth-width)/2,(screen.AvailHeight-height)/2
End Sub

Sub OnClickButtonSyncNow()

    ' Box A
    If BoxAA.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAA"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxAB.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAB"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxAC.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAC"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxAD.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAD"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxAE.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAE"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    ' Box B
    If BoxBA.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBA"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxBB.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBB"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxBC.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBC"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxBD.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBD"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxBE.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBE"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    MsgBox "All checkboxes are processed"

End Sub

Sub ExitTool()
    window.close()
End Sub
</script>

<body bgcolor="firebrick">

<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:normal; padding-top:0px ;padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left:0px ;border-style:solid; border-width:0px; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; padding-top:5px ;padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left:0px ;border-style:solid; border-width:0px; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-header{color:#FFFB00; font-size:22px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important;}
.tg .tg-text{color:white; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important; vertical-align:top}
.button {height:50px; width:136px; font-weight:bold; background-color:#555555; border: 2px solid #FFFB00; color:white; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; font-size:16px;}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-header">Box A</th>
    <th class="tg-header">Box B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="AA">AA</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BA">BA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="AB">AB</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BB">BB</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="AC">AC</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BC">BC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="AD">AD</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BD">BD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="AE">AE</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BE">BE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" class="button" name="SyncNow" id="SyncNow" value="Sync Now" onclick="OnClickButtonSyncNow">
<input type="button" class="button" name="Exit" id="Exit" value="Exit" onclick="ExitTool">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag (at least one action done) and a loop:

```
Sub OnClickButtonSyncNow()

    Dim bF : bF = False
    Dim c1, c2
    For Each c1 In Split("A B")
        For Each c2 In Split("A B C D")
            Dim n : n = c1 & c2
            Dim b : Set b = document.getElementById(n)
            If b.Checked Then
               MsgBox n
               bF = True
             End If
        Next
    Next
    If bF Then
       MsgBox "all done"
    Else
       MsgBox "nice try"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly for my given example. But what if I needed to change the `name=` value to something different e.g. Data this and Data that.
I'm a bit confused how the `document.getElementById(n)` works, because there are no `id=` given in my html part.

Answer (score 0):

My current code, thanks to [Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603855/ekkehard-horner).
Improvement suggestions are always welcome.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sync Tool</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Sync Tool"
  ID="SyncTool"
  VERSION="1.0.0"
  BORDER="dialog"
  MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  SCROLL="no"
  SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
  CONTEXTMENU="no"
  SELECTION="no"/>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Sub Window_OnLoad
    Dim width,height
    width=330
    height=310
    self.ResizeTo width,height
    self.MoveTo (screen.AvailWidth-width)/2,(screen.AvailHeight-height)/2
End Sub

Sub OnClickButtonSyncNow()

    ' Box A
    If BoxAA.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAA"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxAB.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAB"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxAC.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAC"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxAD.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAD"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxAE.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxAE"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    ' Box B
    If BoxBA.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBA"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxBB.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBB"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxBC.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBC"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxBD.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBD"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    If BoxBE.checked Then
        MsgBox "BoxBE"
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If

    Dim bF : bF = False
    Dim c1
        For Each c1 In Split("A B C D E F G H I J")
            Dim n : n = c1
            Dim b : Set b = document.getElementById(n)
            If b.Checked Then
               bF = True
             End If
        Next
    If bF Then
       MsgBox "all done"
    Else
       MsgBox "nothing selected"
    End If

End Sub

Sub ExitTool()
    window.close()
End Sub
</script>

<body bgcolor="firebrick">

<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:normal; padding-top:0px ;padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left:0px ;border-style:solid; border-width:0px; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; padding-top:5px ;padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left:0px ;border-style:solid; border-width:0px; overflow:hidden; word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-header{color:#FFFB00; font-size:22px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important;}
.tg .tg-text{color:white; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif !important; vertical-align:top}
.button {height:50px; width:136px; font-weight:bold; background-color:#555555; border: 2px solid #FFFB00; color:white; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; font-size:16px;}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-header">Box A</th>
    <th class="tg-header">Box B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxAA" id="A">AA</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxBA" id="B">BA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxAB" id="C">AB</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxBB" id="D">BB</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxAC" id="E">AC</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxBC" id="F">BC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxAD" id="G">AD</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxBD" id="H">BD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxAE" id="I">AE</td>
    <td class="tg-text"><input type="checkbox" name="BoxBE" id="J">BE</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" class="button" name="SyncNow" id="SyncNow" value="Sync Now" onclick="OnClickButtonSyncNow">
<input type="button" class="button" name="Exit" id="Exit" value="Exit" onclick="ExitTool">

</body>
</html>
```